# Error: Output stream closed when trying to stream to express server using ffmpeg

Tags: express, ffmpeg, streaming, fluent-ffmpeg, ytdl

I'm getting to stream ytdl audio to my express server using ffmpeg but I'm always getting "Output stream closed"

there's my code

```
const express = require('express')
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')

const app = express()

app.set('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mp3')

    ffmpeg(await ytdl(req.params.id, { format: 'audioonly', quality: 'highestaudio' }))
        .toFormat('mp3')
        .pipe(res, { end: true })
})
```

Comment: help me god please

Comment: Not sure.. but as per docs, ytdl returns a stream while ffmpeg expects a file...
You could try to write to file from ytdl and later stream from the same file location

Comment: @KaranGaur ffmpeg expects a string or a stream.Readable which ytdl is a stream.Readable

Comment: Hi, Did you managed to get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the timeout problem:

```
    Error: Output stream closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\MYPATH\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:491:25)
```

I accessed the fluent-ffmpeg `processor.js` file and the following function appeared:

```js
    setTimeout(function() {
      emitEnd(new Error('Output stream closed'));
      ffmpegProc.kill();
    }, 20);
```

I commented out the whole function. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it worked great for me.

Comment: I created a patch where put 200 instead of 20. Worked nicely for me!

Answer (score 0):

Setting Content-Disposition header might help you:

```js
res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`),
```

*Reference: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/470#issuecomment-160200925*

But this is not a great solution

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to fetch an array of data by running multiple instances of ffmpeg to pipe. This error is likely due to an issue with how FFmpeg is being used to create multiple streams at once and interfere with each other in the process.

The solution for me was to send requests individually. I know it is not a direct solution but a workaround to think about.